# Cable TV Directional Coupler specifications - What SB means?

Tags: signal, wave, telecommunications

I have one Holland directional couples with this specifications:

- **In DCG-20SB**
- Directional Coupler
- 5-1000 MHz

Cable In/Out:

- In DCG
- Out 12SB
- Tap

Similar one (this is 9SB):

[image]

What does 20SB means? Can I switch it for one having 12SB instead of 20SB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SB is just part of their component part number which seems to correlate with dB on the tap.

This is a 12dB tap is 8 dB stronger but main feedthru will be about 0.2 dB less

Different taps  are made for distributing signals to difference populations of users.

If all the clients are together within very (assumed low loss) cable length then an N-way equal splitter is used. But if distributed among many more than 12 clients then directional couplers are used to feed a drop (dB) then cary to next user.

A splitter is also the same as DC-3 which drops ~3.5dB splitting power in half. DC means Directional Coupler in this case.  So a DC-12 or DC-16 splits or "couples" or "taps" a small fraction of -N dB of the signal power, so normally the signal must be boosted at source by more than this in order to for a small sample tap to be dropped then sent to the next coupler.

Splitters are basically used "Star" topology and Directional Couplers for "daisy-chain" tapped topology.

Comment: I have one 16SB, so it is 4dB stronger, do I need to worry about damaging my cable TV receptor switching to this one?

Comment: can you explain why you want to replace it? and where input and two outputs go?

Comment: Because the 20dB is not working anymore, it is fully rusty. The outputs goes to cable TV receptors.

Answer (score 0):

Directional Coupler, 20dB, **S**older**b**ack: DCG-20SB

Comment: I guess other types are not  soldered on back for some reason.  e.g. Screwed fronts http://www.techtoolsupply.com/v/vspfiles/photos/GHT2-20-2T.jpg  I see

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75    I have seen the term sealed back used as well, basically to reduce emi.